# Your list XML update URL failed, please check the XML file's structure

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

To whom it may concern:
I uploaded a new extension in JED using submit extension button.
the message I got after saving is : Your list XML update URL failed, please check the XML file's structure
the tags to server in manifest file of component is checked and server type is extension.
The file in my server contains only updates and update tags,
Because I still have no update to add. Path to this file is checked too.
what could be wrong?
Kian William

Comment: This is not the place to for JED related issues. Please submit a ticket to the JED team and they'll contact you: https://extensions.joomla.org/support/support-tickets/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue needs to be taken up with the JED team

Comment: I already did before I send my message here, no response.

Comment: Please give them some time. There are thousands of extensions, lots of other support tickets, and a fairly small team.

Comment: I am aware of that, yet when you assign a ticket, there has always been an automatic email message from their side regarding the ticket is received, I have not received it this time.

Comment: I am voting to leave this question open. While it is not strictly a Joomla development question, in some ways it is. Part of developing an extension is creating and modifying the proper XML update servers for it (if it is being added to the JED). Knowing the difference between an extension update server and the JED remote management hook is important to a developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML Update URL is not the same thing as your UpdateServer XML Url. The JED has now provided an automated way of updating listings on the site by using there XML Update URL. The XML UPdate URL is a url on your site that the JED polls to look for updates about your specified extension. Just remove that line from your listing, if you are not doing automated JED updates it is not needed.

This in no way affects your extension update server for your extension.

Comment: Hi,I did as you advised and the message is gone now. My extension is in pending state now with no other message, just waiting to be checked by their auto-checker.Thank you and best regards

Comment: Glad I could help. It looks like the JEDs documentation page is currently offline for help with creating a Remote Update Server for extensions.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue please mark this question as answered to help us keep the joomla stackexchange organized.

Comment: Greetings Terry: thanks to you, my extension is listed now in JED. KianWilliam

Comment: Congrats ;) glad you got it sorted.